# How to let user activate account through devise confirmations email link locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to confirm user accounts in test mode while using devise and rails. Here's the scenario. I changed the devise confirmation email that is sent into a partial that is rendered after a user has successfully signed up. Problem is it shows the following error "undefined method email". Here's my confirmation partial.

```
Welcome <%= @resource.email %>!
```

You can confirm your account through the link below:

<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %>

. And below is my application_helper in order to access the resource details.

```
def resource_name
        :user
    end
```

`def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

Is `@resource` actually the user in application_helper?  I know if it is nil it will be assigned a new `User`, but what is it before it assigns it?

I suspect `@resource` isn't a `User`, but something else (a something that doesn't have an `email` field).

Comment: Yes it is. or i guess since my model is called user.

Comment: Can you check (either debug, or I guess just `throw @resource`).

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is if @resource is actually a `User` and `User` has an `email` attribute then you wouldn't get that error.  Therefore either `@resource` isn't actually an instance of `User` (or your `User` doesn't have an email attribute which isn't likely).  So I'm saying that you're getting something other than what you're expecting from the `@resource` object.  How are you setting `@resource` in the controller?